# Polymorphism with Static Methods

Tags: java

I'm creating a Mario clone where everything on the screen is an instance of `ScreenElement`. A `ScreenElement` is Landable if it can be landed on by Mario.

```
public class ScreenElement {
    public boolean isLandable() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Some classes override `isLandable`, for example:

```
public class GrassBlock extends ScreenElement {
    @Override
    public boolean isLandable() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And classes that don't override `isLandable` should inherit it from the closest super class that does. That is to say, I need polymorphism.
Now this all works fine as long as `isLandable` is an instance method. However whether or not a given `ScreenElement` is Landable depends on the class, not the instance. So `isLandable` should really be static. But if I make it static, I cannot override it or inherit in sub classes that don't explicitly define it. Is there a simple workaround to this problem.

EDIT:
I do realize that the way I have it set up right now, it is working correctly but the reason I am bringing this up is because I have encountered a problem. Given a class that extends `ScreenElement`, I need to find out the result of `isLandable`. The only thing I could think of was this:

```
private <S extends ScreenElement> boolean isThisLandable(Class<S> category) {
    return category.newInstance().isLandable();
}
```

I have to create a new instance to figure out something that doesn't depend on the instance, and this seems unnatural.

EDIT 2: Here's the specific piece of code that I'm dealing with.

```
private <S extends ScreenElement> S getGenericScreenElement(Mario mario, Class<S> category) {
    for (ScreenElement element : screenElements) {
        if (category.isInstance(element)) {
            S elementToTest = category.cast(element);
            if (elementToTest.isLandable()) {
                //return elementToTest if it matches additional criteria
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Why not make a `LandableElement` class that inherits `ScreenElement` and is inherited by landable elements? Then you can override the method in `Landable Element` or alternatively just use `instanceof LandableElement` to check if objects are landable.

Comment: @Zar, `instanceof` is probably not the best advice; in general or otherwise.

Comment: @Zar In some cases, I have a sub class override `isLandable` a second time to set it back to false.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils What's so bad about using instanceof?

Comment: If your code is checking if an object is an `instanceof` this or that, there's, with little exception, a better design. One that will improve your code and life.

Comment: @Amaar I would assume that, in a particular situation when you are dealing with one of these classes, you could just check one of them to see if they are land able no? I don't see why you need to access it statically. Can you give us a piece of code that shows how this is a problem?

Comment: @Zachery I'm not really sure if this is a problem anymore. I originally felt like it was awkward creating an instance to check something that doesn't depend on that instance; but I guess it's okay since I can't seem to find a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You're overthinking this.

In a nutshell, this code is doing *exactly* what you want it to do.

Here's what happens.

Your parent class, `ScreenElement`, defines by the `isLandable()` method by default, and it is always set to return `false`.  By creating a new class that is a `ScreenElement`, if they wish to change this behavior, they must override that method to do so.

The fact that your `GrassBlock` *does* override this method is indicative that any *instance* of a `GrassBlock` will register `true` if its `isLandable()` property is checked.

---

With your code revision, you're *still* overthinking this.

**All you need to do** when you attempt to use an instance of `ScreenElement` - be that an instance of `ScreenElement` or any of its children - is to just *call the method*.

You shouldn't care about that property until you decide to check it, during its run.  The way you're checking it now makes very little sense at all.

As an example:

```
ScreenElement vanillaElement = new ScreenElement();
GrassBlock block = new GrassBlock();

System.out.println(vanillaElement.isLandable()); // will print false
System.out.println(block.isLandable()); // will print true
```

More explicitly, with your sample code, you can greatly reduce it.  Many of your statements to check against the type are unnecessary, especially when casting.  You're guaranteed to have nothing *more* than a `ScreenElement`, and since `isLandable()` is defined on at least that, you will never run into a scenario in which you cannot call that method.

The above will turn your code into this.  I leave the addition of your `Mario` parameter up to you since its purpose is unclear in this method.

```
private ScreenElement getGenericScreenElement(Mario mario) {
    for (ScreenElement element : screenElements) {
        if (element.isLandable()) {
            //return element if it matches additional criteria
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Yes your right, and it is working correctly now. However, I have encountered another problem which is why I'm bringing this up. Check out the edit I made to my question.

Comment: @Amaar:  I've revised my answer.  You're still overthinking this.

Comment: So your suggesting that I leave it as an instance method, and create an instance if I need to figure out if a particular class is Landable.

Comment: @Amaar:  I would presume that you already *have* an instance at this point.  Otherwise, how would you be interacting with it?

Comment: With an object of type `Class<? extends ScreenElement>`.

Comment: @Amaar: Unless you're doing something that you're not revealing, you should be `new`ing an instance rather than fiddling with `Class`. That's more messing with the object via reflection as opposed to doing anything with polymorphism.

Comment: I wanted to add that this is the correct answer and that OP is overthinking this. ScreenElements aren't landable unless they are of a type that overrides landable() and has it return true. If you want to see if an instance of ScreenElement is landable CALL THE METHOD for that element. It will tell you if it is landable or not.

Comment: Yes, I see your point now. I was originally weirded out by having an instance method for something that is class related, but I see that this is the simplest way to go about it now. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Your completely right, however I still need the second parameter because that way I can check if Mario has landed on a specific `ScreenElement`. For example, I can call `getGenericScreenElement(mario, Enemy.class)` to see if Mario has killed an Enemy.

Comment: In that case, you'd want to pass a concrete instance of `ScreenElement`.  You'd also want to pass a concrete instance of `Enemy` instead of messing around with the class.  Again, that's more polymorphism and less OO.

Comment: @Makoto Can you elaborate please. I'm not sure what you mean by pass a concrete instance of `Enemy`.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you need the methods to be overrideable and you want to do polymorphic dispatching means that they should not be static methods.

> However whether or not a given ScreenElement is Landable depends on the class, not the instance.

So make the methods instance methods *without* using the instance state.

Comment: I see your point. In fact that is how I have it set up right now. The thing is, I have encountered a case where I have a given class and need to use the    `isLandable` method. The only way that I can get this done is by creating an instance of the class just to be able to call this method, which seems unnatural.